# Como colocar duas funções no onclick para uma ser feita se a outra funcionar

Tags: javascript

Eu estou aprendendo javaScript e tive uma dúvida, quando eu coloco:

```
<button onclick=  "this. innerHTML =  prompt('Qual o nome do botão?'); ">qual o nome do botão</button>
```

Consigo mudar o nome do botão, com isso eu queria que quando eu colocasse para o botão se chamar: Sair da pagina, esse mesmo botão recebesse outra função, que é a de retornar a pagina anterior. Queria saber se tem como e se tiver, como poderia fazer?

Comment: que tal algo como `onclick="if (function1()) function2();`? claro que a primeira function deve retornar true/false

Comment: Para executar uma função após sair da página, vc pode acionar o evento unload nesta mesma página: `window.addEventListener('unload', suaFuncaoDeRetorno)`. Dentro dessa função: `suaFuncaoDeRetorno` pode colocar tipo `history.back(0);` ou o endereço que você estava querendo chamar, ou mesmo travar a saída...

Answer (score 1):

Em navegadores modernos registre um ou mais de um ouvintes de eventos com [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
Se vários ouvintes de eventos estiverem anexados ao mesmo elemento para o mesmo tipo de evento, eles serão chamados na ordem em que foram adicionados.

Para evitar que outros ouvintes de um mesmo evento sejam chamados use [`Event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation).

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  const nome = (prompt('Qual o nome do botão?') ?? "qual o nome do botão").toLowerCase();
  if (nome == "sair da página") {
    console.log("Saindo da página....");
    return;
  } 
  evt.target.innerText = nome;
  evt.stopImmediatePropagation();            //Evita que os outros ouvintes do evento click sejam acionados.
});

btn.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  console.log("...chamando o método para deixar a página");
  window.history.back();                     //Não funciona no sandbox.
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">qual o nome do botão</button>
```

A mesma tarefa, sem recorrer uma fila de eventos:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  const nome = (prompt('Qual o nome do botão?') ?? "qual o nome do botão").toLowerCase();
  if (nome == "sair da página") {
    console.log("Saindo da página....");
    window.history.back();                    //Não funciona no sandbox.
    return;
  } 
  evt.target.innerText = nome;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">qual o nome do botão</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer criar um título que seria a ação do botão e depois executá-la:

```
<button onclick="executeButton(this)">qual o nome do botão</button>
<script>
function executeButton(el) {
   var p = prompt('qual o nome do botão?');
   if (p != 'Sair da página') {
      el.innerHTML = p;
   } else {
     window.location = '/sair.html'
   }

}
</script>
```

Aqui o [fiddle do exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/pnezgv24/).

Answer (score -1):

Olá, uma forma simples de se fazer isso é emcapsulando as suas funções em um a terceira:
EX:
JS:

```
    const funcao1 = (event) => {...}
    const funcao2 = (event) => {...}
    const funcaoEmcapsulada = (event) => {
       funcao1(event);
       funcao2(event);
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <button onclick="funcaoEmcapsulada">qual o nome do botão</button>
```